# Type Erasure in Java

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure

Type erasure is supposed to erase all generic information...
If this is the case how does a library like GSON use generics to determine what type to deserialize to?

e.g.

```
private Map<String,Date> tenordates;
```

This will deserialize to `<String,Date>`
where as

```
private Map<Date,Date> tenordates;
```

will deserialize to `<Date,Date>`

so somehow its using the generic info at runtime.

Comment: may be reflection ..I haven't checked the code .

Comment: possible duplicate of [getSimpleNameWithGenerics(Class<?> clazz)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707042/getsimplenamewithgenericsclass-clazz)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Type erasure does not erase all type information. It does not delete it from class, field, return type and parameter definitions. The type information in the following examples is retained:

```
public class Foo extends List<Bar> { ..}

private List<Foo> foos;

public List<Foo> getFoos() {..}

public void doSomething(List<Foo> foos) {..}
```

This is accesible via reflection - the [`java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html). You can check whether a given `Type` is `instanceof` that class, cast to it and obtain the type information.