# What are the exceptions to type erasure in Java?

Tags: java, generics, reflection, type-erasure

I have seen it mentioned on some places online that in some situations it is possible to use the reflection API to get back information about generic data types which I thought would be lost through type erasure.

I am looking for complete list of the situations where type erasure is not complete i.e. something is still accessible via reflection. A Good list of examples and associated reflection code that can get at the generic types would be excellent.

**UPDATE** http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/generics.html had exactly the examples I was looking for.

Comment: if you voted to close this question please please a comment and tell me why?

Comment: links to those places would be helpful.

Comment: @Thilo http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713438/type-erasure-in-java is an example of a place that mentions that not all type info is lost.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it just comes down to this:

- No object instance stores any type information.
- The classes, however, retain all their generic signatures (otherwise you could not have any generic type checking at compile time)

So, using reflection, you can read the generic type information for a given class.

Example:

```
 class MyList extends ArrayList<MyObject>{}

 List<MyObject> x = new MyList();
```

Reflection will tell you that this is a List of MyObject (because this information is compiled into the MyList class).

but

```
List<MyObject> x = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
```

Reflection will not tell you anything useful (because the ArrayList *class* knows nothing about MyObject).

Comment: +1 The reason any generic information is retained is for the `javac` compiler to do its work. e.g. you have to be able to compile code using the generics in code already compiled correctly.

Comment: In addition to the superclass, the generics in the types of non-private fields, and method argument and return types, are also all there, for the purposes of type checking.

Comment: Yes, all those are part of the class definition. The example above was not meant to be exhaustive. But note that in all those cases, the generics are available for the field/argument/return type *definition* (signature), not for the actual run-time value of any object assigned to them..

Answer (score 2):

The general idea is that if you create a named or anonymous class that is a subclass of a generic type with particular types for the type parameters, then the subclass is not generic and not subject to type erasure.  Assuming that you can get hold of the `Class` object for the subclass, you can use reflection on that object to find out what the parameter types are.

When you think about it, this is not really an "exception" to the erasure rule.  Rather, it is arranging that the class in question is not generic by explicitly reifying it.

Comment: "to find out what the parameter types are" No, you are finding out the type parameters of the superclass that it extends.