# Getting raw class from a type erased Java object

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure, raw-types

I have an object and i need to get the [Type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Type.html) for that object. I need to get the rawType from an erased object.

For example i have a class

```
class Blah{}

class Dummy extends Blah{}

class A<T extends Blah>
{
}

i create a instance for A like this new A<Dummy>().
```

I need to get the raw type of the created object, and i see Apache has TypeUtils getRawClass. But it takes in a java Type. I have the actual instance but how do i get the Type from that.  doing object.getClass() doesnt seem to help and the raw type isnt recovered. Would appreciate some input.

EDIT: 
Thanks for the response, just like the answers below i couldnt find any way to get the actual type. The only suggestion to retain the type was to use the super type tokens. http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html

Comment: This `A.class.getTypeParameters()[0].getBounds()[0]` will return `Blah`

Answer (score 4):

> I have the actual instance but how do i get the Type from that

That is not possible, thanks to generics type erasure.

At run-time the instance has no record of its generic type.

See this [other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11822904/what-are-the-exceptions-to-type-erasure-in-java?rq=1) for some more discussion.

Comment: So in your example, reflection can give you `Blah` (the compile-time type), but not `Dummy` (the runtime type, which of course extends `Blah`).

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Thilo generic information is available at compile-time. If you need it then you have to store it somewhere in the object itself.

Sample code:

```
class A<T extends Blah> {

    private Class<T> type;

    public A(Class<T> type) { // class must be exactly same as type of object
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Class<T> getType() {
        return type;
    }
}

...

A<Dummy> a = new A<Dummy>(Dummy.class); // only Dummy.class is the valid argument
System.out.println(a.getType().getName());   // com.x.y.z.Dummy

...
A<Dummy> a = new A<Dummy>(Blah.class); // not valid, compile time error
A<Dummy> a = new A<Dummy>(Dummy2.class); // not valid, compile time error
A<Dummy> a = new A<Dummy>(XYZ.class); // not valid, compile time error
```