# Specify Concrete type of a specific Generic Collection Field in Jackson without Annotations

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a class which has a generic collection field

```
class Test {
  List<E> aList;
}
```

I want to deserialize this using Jackson. How can i specify the type of collection to use for this specific field, not for all lists in the object, without using annotations (as I cannot change the existing class).

I am a beginner in Jackson, so i don't know how to write a custom deserializer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW...

> without using annotations (as I cannot change the existing class)

[Jackson's Mix-Ins feature](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations) is available to work around this problem.

> i don't know how to write a custom deserializer

Though not completely up to date with the latest Jackson release, the Jackson Wiki pages on [custom deserialization](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomDeserializers) and [custom creators](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureCreators) are still relevant.

Also, in [Gson v Jackson - Part 3 on InstanceCreator for a Parameterized Type](http://programmerbruce.blogspot.com/2011/07/gson-v-jackson-part-3.html#TOC-InstanceCreator-for-a-Parameterized), I posted a couple different solutions to a similar problem.

Comment: What if the type of a list is polymorphic...and concrete type is determined at runtime, so we cannot specify that in a mixin?

Comment: Do the examples at http://programmerbruce.blogspot.com/2011/05/deserialize-json-with-jackson-into.html help?  If you're still stuck, I recommend posting a new question to SO, with complete minimal code examples.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to do anything Jackson seems to be able to figure out the data type of the List, I ran into this issue last week and it turned out that the Java Generic information is avilable via reflection see [What are the exceptions to type erasure in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11822904/what-are-the-exceptions-to-type-erasure-in-java) and [Type Erasure in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713438/type-erasure-in-java)

I wrote the following test program to better understand it.

```
public class GenericObject {
        public Map<Integer,String> map = new HashMap<>();
        private List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();  
        private List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<>(); 

        public List<Integer> getIntegers() {
            return integers;
        }

        public void setIntegers(List<Integer> integers) {
            this.integers = integers;
        }

        public List<Date> getDates() {
            return dates;
        }

        public void setDates(List<Date> dates) {
            this.dates = dates;
        }

        public void setIntegersList(Integer... ints)
        {
            for (Integer integer : ints) {
                integers.add(integer);
            }
        }

    public void setDatesList(Date... dates)
    {
        for (Date date : dates) {
            this.dates.add(date);
        }
    }

public void runtimeGenericTypes()
{
    try {

        Field field  = GenericObject.class.getField("map");
        System.out.println("Field has type " + field.getType());
        ParameterizedType genericType = (ParameterizedType) field.getGenericType();
        Type[] actualTypeArguments2 = genericType.getActualTypeArguments();
        for (Type type : actualTypeArguments2) {
            System.out.println("Gerenic field types: " + type);
        }


        // get the return type of a generic method 
        Method method =GenericObject.class.getMethod("getIntegers",null);
        Class<?> returnType = method.getReturnType();
        System.out.println(returnType);

        Type genericReturnType = method.getGenericReturnType();
        ParameterizedType parameterizedType = (ParameterizedType) genericReturnType;
        Type[] actualTypeArguments = parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments();
        for (Type type : actualTypeArguments) {
            System.out.println(type);
        }

        System.out.println(genericReturnType);


        // get the parameter type of a generic method 
        Method set = GenericObject.class.getMethod("setIntegers", List.class);
        Class<?>[] parameterTypes = set.getParameterTypes();
        for (Class<?> class1 : parameterTypes) {
            System.out.println("Parameter type " + class1);
        }
        Type[] genericParameterTypes = set.getGenericParameterTypes();
        for (Type type : genericParameterTypes) {
            ParameterizedType parameterizedType2 = (ParameterizedType) type;
            parameterizedType2.getActualTypeArguments();
            for (Type type2 : genericParameterTypes) {
                System.out.println(" Paratermer type is: " + type2);
            }
        }

    } catch (SecurityException | NoSuchMethodException | NoSuchFieldException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    TypeVariable<?>[] typeParameters = dates.getClass().getTypeParameters();
    for (TypeVariable<?> typeVariable : typeParameters) {

        System.out.println(typeVariable);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {



    GenericObject object = new GenericObject();
    object.setIntegersList(1,2,4,5,5);
    object.setDatesList(new Date());

    object.runtimeGenericTypes();

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.INDENT_OUTPUT,true);
    DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.LONG);
    mapper.setDateFormat(df);

        String json;
        try {
            json = mapper.writeValueAsString(object);
            System.out.println(json);

            GenericObject readObject = mapper.readValue(json, GenericObject.class);
            List<Integer>  readIntegers = readObject.getIntegers();
            for (Integer integer : readIntegers) {
                System.out.println(integer);
            }
            List<Date> dates2 = readObject.getDates();
            for (Date date : dates2) {
                System.out.println(date);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


}
```

}

Comment: You may be right, but its not working for me, actually the object I am trying to serialize & deserialize is generated using JAXB 1 implementation, so it is not recognising the type of a list. Isn't there any method of specifying this in the objectMapper

Comment: does the object have JAXB annotations on it? if so then maybe Jackson is reading these JAXB annotations and getting confused.