# Create a ArrayList of data class objects from a String in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a Kotlin data class

`data class Item (val content: String) {}`

In my app I use an `myData: ArrayList<Item>`.

To provide persistant storage the app writes this list to a file everytime it is changed:
`configFile.writeText(myData.toString())`

At startup it reads the file and with `configfile.readFile()`. The returned string look like this:
`[Item(content=Click #1), Item(content=Click #2)]`

How can I create the arraylist from this string?

Comment: I **very strongly** recommend that you save the data in a structured format, such as JSON. You then use the associated parser (e.g., a JSON parser) for that format to convert the string back into objects.

Comment: I decided to go with https://github.com/cbeust/klaxon thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can write data in some well known format such as `JSON` or `XML`. You can still parse your written string, but JSON / XML can be preferrable.

For reading / writing JSON / XML, you can use jackson library which is quite easy to use.
Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33402673/3295987) for quickstart.

Comment: As mentioned above: I decided to go with https://github.com/cbeust/klaxon. Thanks anyways.