# Deserialization JSON into a List<SomeType> with Kotlin + Jackson - Deserialization Exception

Tags: arrays, json, kotlin, jackson, jackson-databind

I have followed below link to read value using mapper from json string, but I could see kind of deserialization exception while executing my code,

[How to use jackson to deserialize to Kotlin collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33368328/how-to-use-jackson-to-deserialize-to-kotlin-collections)

**Code:**

```
private fun parseCountry(): List<Country> {
    val map = jacksonObjectMapper()
    val countryAsString = """[
                                {
                                  "countryCode": "IND",
                                  "countryName": "INDIA"
                                }
                             ]"""
    return map.readValue(countryAsString)
}
```

**Country.kt**

```
data class Country(
    val countryCode: String,
    val countryName: String)
```

**Exception:**

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is feign.codec.DecodeException: Error while extracting response for type [java.util.List<com.test.Country>] and content type [application/json;charset=UTF-8]; nested exception is 

org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList<com.test.Country>` out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList<com.test.Country>` out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]

    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:72)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:167)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
    at com.financing.platform.mdc.filters.UserMdcFilter.doFilter(UserMdcFilter.java:23)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
```

I tried to dig so much and find root cause but couldn't able to find out, so reaching out to experts here for possible solutions.

PS: Versions I'm using are

```
<kotlin.version>1.3.70</kotlin.version>
<jackson.version>2.9.10</jackson.version>
```

Answer (score 0):

Jackson has a problem with kotlin data classes. Because it needs to have a default no argument constructor and setters in the attributes.

To solve that you can register the kotlin module to the jackson mapper so you can deserialize data classes withour problem.

First you have to add the dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And then register the module in your jacksonObjectMapper

```
val mapper = ObjectMapper().registerModule(KotlinModule())
```

Once you have done this it should not fail

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin

Comment: I tried your solution but it didn't work, suspecting as happening because of "nested exception is feign.codec.DecodeException" (kind of encoder and decoder issue while integrating with feign calls)