# Retrieving data from CBOR ByteArray

Tags: kotlin, serialization, jackson, cbor

I am trying to serialize a map into CBOR in Kotlin with the Jackson CBOR Dataformats Library, this works fine if the key is a String , I can retrieve the value of that key easily but when the key in an Int, it returns null to me for every get I do, If I print out the output from values(), it gives me all values from all keys.

Code looks like this :

```
val mapper = CBORMapper()
val map = HashMap<Any,Any>()
map[123] = intArrayOf(22,67,2)
map[456] = intArrayOf(34,12,1)
val cborData = mapper.writeValueAsBytes(map)
println(cborData.toHex())
val deserialized = mapper.readValue(cborData, HashMap<Any,Any>().javaClass)
println(deserialized.get(123)) // returns null
println(values()) // returns all values
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to iterate over keys and check the type:

```
deserialized.keys.iterator().next().javaClass
```

Above code, in your case should print:

```
123 - class java.lang.String
456 - class java.lang.String
```

And:

```
println(deserialized.get("123"))
```

prints:

```
[22, 67, 2]
```

Take a look on [documentation](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-binary/tree/master/cbor):

> Module extends standard Jackson streaming API (JsonFactory,
> JsonParser, JsonGenerator), and as such works seamlessly with all the
> higher level data abstractions (data binding, tree model, and
> pluggable extensions).

You can force type using `Kotlin's` `readValue` method:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.readValue
```

and use it like this:

```
val deserialized = mapper.readValue<Map<Int, IntArray>>(cborData)
deserialized.keys.forEach { key -> println("$key - ${key.javaClass}") }
println(Arrays.toString(deserialized[123]))
```

Above code prints:

```
456 - int
123 - int
[22, 67, 2]
```

See also:

- [How to use jackson to deserialize to Kotlin collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33368328/how-to-use-jackson-to-deserialize-to-kotlin-collections)

Comment: I see, yea it is a String indeed, can I not make it work with Integers?

Comment: @YasinEraslan, take a look on my updated answer