# unit-of-measurement filter by quantity

Tags: java, units-of-measurement, jsr363

we are using the great [unit-of-measurement](https://github.com/unitsofmeasurement) framework to manage units dynamically. I have the requirement to filter a list of units by quantity. E.g. display all mass (tonne, kg ....). The list results in an generic capture list (which is not ideal - i know). The generic information does not exist at runtime (only at compile time). However for the [unit](https://github.com/unitsofmeasurement/unit-api/blob/master/src/main/java/javax/measure/Unit.java) interface an implementation exists to check the compatibility exists:

- boolean isCompatible(Unit that);

  ```
  @Test
  public void testCompatible_ByUnit(){
      Unit<Mass> kilogram = Units.KILOGRAM;
      Unit<Mass> tonne = NonSI.TONNE;

      assertTrue(kilogram.isCompatible(tonne));
  }
  ```

Is there any interface to check the compatiblity by [quantity](https://github.com/unitsofmeasurement/unit-api/blob/master/src/main/java/javax/measure/Quantity.java)?

Non working example with quantity [Mass](https://github.com/unitsofmeasurement/unit-api/blob/master/src/main/java/javax/measure/quantity/Mass.java).

```
    @Test
    public void testCompatible_FilterByQuantityAndCapture(){
        Unit<?> kilogram = Units.KILOGRAM;
        // wish: interface does not exist
        assertTrue(kilogram.isCompatible(Mass.class));
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common problem of the Java language because Java so far does not offer [Reified Generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879855/what-are-reified-generics-how-do-they-solve-type-erasure-problems-and-why-cant).

I'm not aware that this feature made it into Java SE 9, so we likely won't see it before Java 10 or later.

```
<Q extends Quantity<Q>> Unit<Q> getUnit(Class<Q> quantityType);
```

returns the default (or system) unit for a given `Quantity` class. And although `Dimension` is more of an "umbrella" to quantities, you may also get a list of all units under a particular dimension.

```
Set<? extends Unit<?>> getUnits(Dimension dimension);
```

In a future version of the API/SPI `SystemOfUnits` may also offer something similar for a `Quantity` class, but it is quite possible this kind of additional method won't make much sense before the underlying Java platform offers reified generics or some other way of better type information than it does toeday.

Comment: Thank you - the workaround with the default (or system) unit for the quantity is working me.

Comment: I'm trying the getUnits() approach with the uom-ri library's `METRE` to essentially retrieve a list of Length-dimensioned units, and keep getting empty sets:

`Set<? extends Unit<?>> units = system.getUnits(METRE.getDimension());`

Any guidance on how I'm misusing the API?  I really need this for a UI for entering/updating quantities.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Did you use the RI or Java SE implementation? We'll try to replicate it and either tell how to change the call or if necessary fix issues.