# How to cast Class<?> to Class<T>?

Tags: java, generics, casting, jackson, type-erasure

I have class with `Class<?>` field. I have a method, which has to cast string to object with help of Jackson.

```
private Class<?> myType = ...;
private String jsonRepresentationOfObject = ....;
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

public <T> T get() {
   return mapper.readValue(jsonRepresentationOfObject, myType);
}
```

Is there any possibility to cast `myType` to `T`? Or it is impossible, because of type erasure?

Comment: Why don't you use `Class<MyType>`?

Comment: @SilverNak I have differents types, so I cannot use it.

Comment: The signature `<T> T get()` says "I don't care what type `myType` is, I expect a `T`". What do you think casting `myType` will accomplish?

Comment: @JFPicard How exactly is this question a duplicate of [Difference between <? super T> and <? extends T> in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4343202/697630)? I don't find it event remotely related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are absolutely sure that the result of `readValue` will be of type `T` you can do this:

```
public <T> T get() {
   return (T)mapper.readValue(jsonRepresentationOfObject, myType);
}
```

You will have to `@SuppressWarnings` for unchecked casts though.

In other languages (like Kotlin which can interop with Java) you can use [`reified generics`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879855/what-are-reified-generics-how-do-they-solve-type-erasure-problems-and-why-cant) but it is not present in Java because of type erasure.

If the result of `readValue` **is** not a `T` then you will get a `ClassCastException` so use this wisely.

Comment: *If the result of readValue is not a `T` then you will get a `ClassCastException`*. Not necessarily. Hence the warning.

Answer (score -1):

It's not possible, thanks to type erasure. This is why some library functions in Java have you pass in an instance of a class that isn't used for anything except doing a `.getClass()`. I'm actually writing very similar code right now and I ended up having a signature on the class of (the equivalent of) `(T returnType)` and then in the `readValue` call, I pass in `returnType.getClass()`.