# How to find all sub classes of implemented interface in java?

Tags: java, reflection

How to get Subclass object using implemented interface, if interface is used as Type Parameter for DynamoDBTypeConverter.(e.g. DynamoDBTypeConverter ).

```
public enum state implements EnumInterface{
    CREATED("0");
}

public enum color implements EnumInterface{
    GREEN("0");
}

public interface EnumInterface{
    void getStatus();
}

public class DynamoDbEnumConverter implements DynamoDBTypeConvereter<String,EnumInterface>{
    public EnumInterface unconvert(String value){
        // find Object run time, EnumInterface represent color or stat
    }
}
```

Get whether Enum interface represents color or state in unconvert method.

Comment: Does `String value` represent an enum type (like color or state), or an enum constant (like `CREATED` or `GREEN`)?

Comment: @VGR Represent the value, for example constant GREEN, I am storing value "0".

Comment: Is there a reason you want to discover your enum classes dynamically?  Why not keep a `Collection<Class<? extends EnumInterface>>` inside your DynamoDbEnumConverter?

Answer (score 0):

Check this page out: [What are Reified Generics? How do they solve Type Erasure problems and why can't they be added without major changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879855/what-are-reified-generics-how-do-they-solve-type-erasure-problems-and-why-cant)

Generics are *erased* in Java.

The only way you're going to get your code to work without hacking around is by providing one instance of the `DynamoDbEnumConverter` for each `EnumInterface`:

```
class DynamoDbEnumConverter<T extends Enum<T> & EnumInterface> implements DynamoDBTypeConvereter<String, T> {
    private Class<T> enumType;

    public DynamoDbEnumConverter(Class<T> enumType) {
        this.enumType = enumType;
    }

    public EnumInterface unconvert(String value) {
        return Enum.valueOf(enumType, value);
    }
}
```

And then:

```
DynamoDbEnumConverter<Color> colorConverter = new DynamoDbEnumConverter<>(Color.class);
```

Comment: Dev wants DynamoDbEnumConverter to look through *all* types which implement EnumInterface, not just one of them.

Comment: Ah - I took "Get whether Enum interface represents color or state in unconvert method" too literally :(