# Generic type in Scala

Tags: java, scala, abstract-class, generic-programming

I started studying recently Scala. And I don't understand why this code is not working. Can anybody help me?

```
import scala.collection.mutable
import scala.collection.mutable.Map

class Bijection[T] (val v: Set[T]) {
  private var addition = 0
  private var reversed = false

  def add(i: Int)(implicit ev: T <:< Int) = {
    addition += i
  }

  def reverse(implicit ev: T <:< String) = {
    reversed = !reversed
  }
}

object Bijection {
  def apply(s: Set[String]): Bijection[String] = {
    println("Hello string")
    Bijection(s)
  }

  def apply[T](s: Set[T]): Bijection[T] = {
    println("Hello T")
    Bijection(s)
  }
}

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    var x = Bijection[String](Set[String]("fd", "fasf"))
  }
}
```

This code should print "Hello"
But I get now next trace.

```
Error:(23, 7) double definition:
def apply(s: Set[String]): Bijection[String] at line 18 and
def apply[T](s: Set[T]): Bijection[T] at line 23
have same type after erasure: (s: scala.collection.immutable.Set)Bijection
  def apply[T](s: Set[T]): Bijection[T] = {
```

Comment: Using new will not call the apply method in main. As the above comment mention you will need to remove the new keyward to call Bijection.apply. (you don't need the [String] type parameter) Finally you will also need to explicitly or implictly provide the expected parameter ignore

Comment: @user you are genius! I am very grateful to you for this question and previous.

Comment: I update question @user can you see that?

Comment: You can't use just `Bijection(s)` in your apply method because that will call the apply method *again*, causing recursion. Instead, call the actual constructor there, and make your primary constructor private.

Comment: Yes but error is not in recursion now.

Answer (score 0):

The JVM doesn't have [reified generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879855/what-are-reified-generics-how-do-they-solve-type-erasure-problems-and-why-cant), instead, it [erases type parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) at runtime, even though they're stored in bytecode. The only reason it has type parameters are to check things at compile time. Because of this, your 2 apply methods will both have the signature.

```
def apply(s: Set): Bijection
```

at runtime.

Because of this, there's no way for the right apply method to be chosen.

Furthermore, you have to call the constructor inside the apply method. If you don't use `new`, then you'll just call the same apply method again, going into infinite recursion.

Instead, you can do something like this. If it's not a string, the implicit parameter will remain null, and you will know that it is not a `String` but some other `T`.

```scala
object Bijection {
  private def applyString(s: Set[String]): Bijection[String] = {
    println("Hello String")
    new Bijection(s)
  }
  
  private def applyT[T](s: Set[T]): Bijection[T] = {
    println("Hello T")
    new Bijection(s)
  }
  
  def apply[T](s: Set[T])(implicit ev: Set[T] =:= Set[String] = null): Bijection[T] =
    if (ev == null) applyT(s) else applyString(s).asInstanceOf[Bijection[T]]
}
```

You don't have to change anything else.

[Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/1bG7SdqBTSmNWWR5dtSH6A)

Comment: Have you tried for another type? Example for Int it doesn't work.

Comment: @archi1998 Did you try again? It should work now. I forgot setting `ev` to null by default