# Wildcards gone wrong

Tags: java, wildcard

I am testing out wild cards, and thought to make a small program

```
public class WildCards {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        order(new Box<Animal>());
        order(new Box<Human>());
        order(new Box<Mammal>());
    }
    public static void order(Box<? extends Mammal> box) {
        System.out.println(box.getContent() + " is a Mammal.");
    }
    public static void order(Box<? super Mammal> box) {
        System.out.println("Mammal is a " + box.getContent());
    }
}

class Thing extends Object {}
class Creature extends Thing {}
class Animal extends Creature {}
class Mammal extends Animal {}
class Primate extends Mammal {}
class Gorilla extends Primate {}
class Human extends Primate {}

class Box<T extends Thing> {
    T object;
    String getContent() {
        return new T().getClass().getName();
    }
}
```

But it isn't working, does anyone know what went wrong?

Comment: Generics are "erased" at compile time, this means that `public static void order(Box<? extends Mammal> box)` and `public static void order(Box<? super Mammal> box) {` will both become `public static void order(Box box) {` which means you now have two methods with the same name.  Change the method names. `return new T().getClass().getName();` is also wrong, you can simply make it `return new getClass().getName();`

Comment: Can you suggest another way of doing that?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 mostly unrelated problems here.

1. The rules state that the identity of a method is its name and its erased parameter types. All methods must have a unique identity. Your 2 `box` methods both look like `void order(Box)` once you apply erasure (toss out all the `<>`, replace any typevars with their lower bound, i.e. given `class Foo<T extends Number>`, to erase 'T', replace it with `Number`. For just `class Foo<T>`, it becomes `Object`, same happens to `class Foo<T super Number>`. Why? Cuz the spec says so. Hence, you can't have 2 methods named `box` like this. Name one of them something else. Or unify them (make one method that accepts a `Box<?>`.
2. Erasure

Generics is a figment of the compiler's imagination; it's compiler-checked documentation. The compiler uses it to link things together; if you declare a new typevar and use it in only one place, it's useless. For example:

```
public class List<E> {
  void add(E elem) { .. }
  E get(int idx) { .. }
}
```

This says: Hey, compiler? When someone writes `List<String> x = new List<String>(); x.add("foo"); x.get(0).toLowerCase()`, link the types together. The same happens here:

```
public static <T> T identity(T in) {return in;}
```

This tells the compiler: When some code *calls* this method, link up the Ts. Whatever the type is of the parameter? That's the type of the whole ordeal.

But that is **just a thing the compiler does**. The compiler applies this logic and then **throws all generics right out the window**.

That means `new T()` **is not java** and there's nothing you can do to make that java. Given 1 Box object, it is **impossible** to know at runtime what the generics of that box is. There is no fixing this.

Answer (score 0):

A basket containing apples, a basket containing pears, and a basket covered with a cloth. Don’t you think these three things are all baskets?

The following, in fact, are all Box types：

```
Box
Box<?>
Box<? extends asd>
Box<? super bcd>
Box<xxx>
```

Therefore, your two order methods are actually duplicated, and you can change their names, one is called order1 and the other is called order2.

As for Wildcards:

You get a basket and find it covered with a cloth,

The man who gave you the basket said, Here are fruits,

So for you, you know, "Oh, there's fruit in it, I don't know what fruit it is, but it's okay, it's edible anyway", that's <? extends fruit>

Answer (score 0):

### Type-erasure

As mentioned in Comments, [Java Generics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java) was implemented with [type-erasure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_erasure) (see [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)). This means the specific class information is not retained after compiling.

The opposite of type-erasure, where class info is retained, is known as reified generics (see [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/879855/642706)). Java does not have reified generics; Java has type-erasure.

Because of type-erasure in Java, your overloaded `order` methods become ambiguous. You will get errors and warnings from your IDE and your compiler about the two `order` methods clashing. After erasure, your two `order` methods are indistinguishable.

```
public static void order( Box box ) { … }
public static void order( Box box ) { … }
```

We can resolve the clash by renaming these:

```
public static void order( Box<? extends Mammal> box ) { … }
public static void order( Box<? super Mammal> box ) { … }
```

… to distinct names:

```
public static void orderMammalOnDownToGorillaAndHuman( Box<? extends Mammal> box ) { … }
public static void orderMammalUpThroughObject( Box<? super Mammal> box ) { … }
```

Also because of type-erasure, your `new T()` code makes no sense, as explained in the [other Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76926157/642706) here, by rzwitserloot. The class info is not known, so `new` cannot be invoked for an undefined class.

### Example code

So let's rename those `order` methods. And make some other tweaks so this code runs.

```java
package work.basil.example.typing;

import java.util.Objects;

public class WildCards
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        WildCards.orderMammalOnDownToGorillaAndHuman ( new Box < Human > ( new Human ( ) ) );
        WildCards.orderMammalOnDownToGorillaAndHuman ( new Box < Mammal > ( new Gorilla ( ) ) );
        WildCards.orderMammalUpThroughObject ( new Box < Animal > ( new Gorilla ( ) ) );
//        WildCards.orderMammalUpThroughObject ( new Box < Primate > (new Gorilla () ) );  // ERROR: incompatible types: work.basil.example.typing.Box<work.basil.example.typing.Primate> cannot be converted to work.basil.example.typing.Box<? super work.basil.example.typing.Mammal>
    }

    public static void orderMammalUpThroughObject ( Box < ? super Mammal > box )
    {
        System.out.println ( box.getClassNameOfMemberField ( ) );
    }

    public static void orderMammalOnDownToGorillaAndHuman ( Box < ? extends Mammal > box )
    {
        System.out.println ( box.getClassNameOfMemberField ( ) );
    }
}

class Thing { }

class Creature extends Thing { }

class Animal extends Creature { }

class Mammal extends Animal { }

class Primate extends Mammal { }

class Gorilla extends Primate { }

class Human extends Primate { }

class Box < T extends Thing >
{
    T object;

    String getClassNameOfMemberField ( )
    {
        return Objects.isNull ( this.object ) ? "null" : this.object.getClass ( ).getName ( );
    }

    public Box ( T object )
    {
        this.object = object;
    }
}
```

When run:

```
work.basil.example.typing.Human
work.basil.example.typing.Gorilla
work.basil.example.typing.Gorilla
```

Notice that our 4th call in `main` fails to compile:

```
WildCards.orderMammalUpThroughObject ( new Box < Primate > (new Gorilla () ) );
```

We get an error:

> incompatible types: work.basil.example.typing.Box<work.basil.example.typing.Primate> cannot be converted to work.basil.example.typing.Box<? super work.basil.example.typing.Mammal>

This makes sense. We said the `orderMammalUpThroughObject` method takes an argument that is a `Box` holding any object whose class is Mammal or higher. This means `Mammal`, `Animal`, `Creature`, `Thing`, and `Object`. But the argument cannot be an object of the subclasses: `Primate`, `Gorilla`, `Human`. So:

- Passing a `Box` of `Animal` with a `Gorilla` works.
- Passing a `Box` of `Primate` with a `Gorilla` fails, a violation of our declaration.

For more discussion of `extends` versus `super`, see [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1911036/642706), and Questions [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1910892/642706) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4343202/642706).